# Permission when deploying gcloud app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I'm trying to deploy an application, but gcloud informs me that I don't have permissions, even though I am the main user of the account with the Owner rule, see: [Deploy console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6pQA.png)

My `gcloud auth list`:

```
              Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
*       hi@myemail.com
        myproject@appspot.gserviceaccount.com

To set the active account, run:
    $ gcloud config set account `ACCOUNT`
```

My `gcloud init` (default project is ok):

```
Welcome! This command will take you through the configuration of gcloud.

Settings from your current configuration [myproject] are:
core:
  account: hi@myemail.com
  disable_usage_reporting: 'False'
  project: myproject

Pick configuration to use:
 [1] Re-initialize this configuration [myproject] with new settings 
 [2] Create a new configuration
```

My IAM & Admin Permissions for project "myproject": [IAM List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jL4rr.png)

How to solve this problem? It is the only project in my account.

Comment: Can you share the full command you are running for this? `gcloud app ...`

Comment: @FerVelvet gcloud app deploy site.yaml --version=2

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is because you're trying to overwrite a deploy with version 2 that is stopped.

The message is very clear in your first image.

> Traffic cannot be allocated to stopped version 2. Please ensure that traffic is only allocated to serving versions.

I'll suggest to check that the deployment in App Engine with version 2 is not stopped or deploy to a new version, for example just to test:

```
gcloud app deploy site.yaml --version=5165165
```

Comment: Changing the version does not work. The problem continues.

Comment: Hi Carlos, I was trying to reproduce the issue but I was not able to do it. I would suggest to contact GCP support where they can help you with this issue.